# Adding datatemplate to listbox and panorama items form program in windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-7.1, panorama-control

I am adding panorama items to panorama controls dynamically, they are adding successfully without any issues

but when i try to add the listbox to panorama item its giving error. I am not able to see the exception also, application automatically closing and I am seeing emulator home screen after that.

Following is my code which I've written to create panorama item and list box

```
lstAnniversaries = new ListBox()
lstAnniversaries.Width = 420;
                        lstAnniversaries.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                        lstAnniversaries.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(FacebookQueries.GetColorFromHexString("#000000"));
                        lstAnniversaries.Background = new SolidColorBrush(FacebookQueries.GetColorFromHexString("#ffffff"));
                        lstAnniversaries.Tap += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(lstUpcoming_Tap);
                        lstAnniversaries.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(@"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
<Grid  Height=""100"" Margin=""0,0,0,0"">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=""90"" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width=""210"" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width=""*"" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source=""{Binding ImageSource}"" Height=""90"" Width=""90"" Margin=""0,0,11,0"" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Column=""1"" Margin=""0,10,0,0"">
                <TextBlock Text=""{Binding NameSource}"" Style=""{StaticResource ProfileNameStyleForTextBlock}""  />
                <StackPanel Orientation=""Horizontal"" Margin=""0,-2,0,0"">
                    <TextBlock Text=""{Binding EventName}"" Foreground=""#000000"" Style=""{StaticResource EventNameStyleForTextBlock}""   />
                    <TextBlock Text=""{Binding EventDate}"" Foreground=""{Binding EventColor}"" Style=""{StaticResource EventDateStyleForTextBlock}""  />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button VerticalAlignment=""Center"" Height=""Auto""     Name=""btnAnniversary"" Width=""75"" Margin=""5,0,0,0"" HorizontalAlignment=""Left""     Visibility=""{Binding EllipseStatus}"" Tag=""{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}""     Click=""btnAnniversary_Click"" Canvas.ZIndex=""1"" Grid.Column=""2"">
                <Image  Source=""/GiftGiv;component/Assets/bubble.png"" />
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>");
                        pan_anniversaries = new PanoramaItem();
                        pan_anniversaries.HeaderTemplate =     (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(@"<DataTemplate     xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""     xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""><TextBlock Text=""anniversaries""    FontSize=""54"" Foreground=""Black"" Margin=""-10,0,0,0""></TextBlock></DataTemplate>");

                        Grid grd = new Grid();
                        grd.Children.Add(lstAnniversaries);

                        pan_anniversaries.Content = grd;

                        PanoramaControl.Items.Add(pan_anniversaries);
```

### EDIT:

**Output windows Text**

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols     'System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols     'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate'
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in     System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
A first chance exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0xf640c32) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xf450ca6) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xf050d2e) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xf820cda) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xecb0e52) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Why do this in code? Why don't you add that DataTemplate to Page or App resources under some key and then retrieve it by that key? Can you see what exception gets raised and where (check the Output window when debugging)

Comment: @igrali `Why don't you add that DataTemplate to Page or App resources under some key and then retrieve it by that key?` Do you know how to do this??

Comment: I Updated my question with output window text, please check it again

Comment: Yes, just add it like it's shown on a picture in this blog post: http://mobileappchallenge.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/datatemplate-and-phoneapplicationpage-resources-gotcha/ Then your page will have that resource. After that, just do something like this: lstAnniversaries.DataTemplate = this.Resources["MyResourceKey"] as DataTemplate; where MyResourceKey is the key you set on your datatemplate. That will simplify your code!

Comment: @igrali Ohh thanks I'll try that and let you know...

Comment: @igrali Yes, its working Creating the DataTemplate from code is giving problem i think

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating `DataTemplates` in code file, add `DataTemplate` code in resources section of Page or APP.

Use following way will resolve the problem as @igrali mentioned in the comments

```
 lstAnniversaries.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["AnniversariesTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
 lstAnniversaries.Style = this.Resources["EventsListStyle"] as Style;
```